# How can I delete my syncronized settings from vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I've been programming for 6 years now, and I wanted to give a fresh new start to my vscode, but I have a problem. I want to "Factory reset" not only the application, but the syncronized settings also. Is there a way to do it? I don't want to simply remove all extensions, but also all of my settings and preferences.
Any suggestion?
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to delete the `.vscode` folder in the root of your project. Or you can go to `code-workspace` and delete the folder with your workspace name.

Answer (score 1):

For Windows you can try :

1. Click on the bottom left gear icon, then click 'Settings Sync is On'
   [image]
2. On the top list open, click 'Settings Sync: turn Off'
   [image]